# Show more than one list item from table in php

Tags: php, list, row

I do the flowing code I want to show all applied jobs in a list but in my code it show only the first job  >>>Please If any one know help me....

```
<?php
        include("includes/db.php");

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//get jobseeker personal information
            //$user=$_SESSION['Email'];          
             $get_jobseeker="select * from jobseeker where Email='$user'";           
             $run_jobseeker=mysqli_query($con, $get_jobseeker);          
             $row_jobseeker=mysqli_fetch_array($run_jobseeker);          
             $ID=$row_jobseeker['ID'];                   
//get jobseeker aplication          
              $get_app="select * from job_application where Jobseeker_ID='$ID'";             
             $run_app=mysqli_query($con, $get_app);          
             $row_app=mysqli_fetch_array($run_app);          
             $Job_entity_id=$row_app['Job_entity_id'];
//get jobseeker job_entity           
        $get_job="select * from job_entity where id='$Job_entity_id'";
        $run_job=mysqli_query($con, $get_job);
        $i=0;
        while($row_job=mysqli_fetch_array($run_job)){
            $id=$row_job['id'];
            $Title=$row_job['Title'];
            $i++;


      ?>
    <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="my_account.php?job=<?php echo $id; ?>"><span><?php echo $Title; ?></span></a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="list-group"> should be before the while no? besides this i see no issue. can you output the result of the query : $run_job?

Comment: Stop Using Capitalized Variables. PHP Is Sensitive To Capitalization And In Your Usecase It Does Not Improve Upon Readability. Why Capitalize `$Title` And Not `$i`?

Comment: @bleuscyther the result only the first item show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does one job_application has more job_entities, or one job_seeker has more job_applications?

I think proper code should be:

```
<div class="list-group">
<?php
        include("includes/db.php");

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//get jobseeker personal information
            //$user=$_SESSION['Email'];          
             $get_jobseeker="select * from jobseeker where Email='$user'";           
             $run_jobseeker=mysqli_query($con, $get_jobseeker);          
             $row_jobseeker=mysqli_fetch_array($run_jobseeker);          
             $ID=$row_jobseeker['ID'];                   
//get jobseeker aplication          
              $get_app="select * from job_application where Jobseeker_ID='$ID'";             
             $run_app=mysqli_query($con, $get_app);          
             $i = 0;
             while ($row_app=mysqli_fetch_array($run_app)) {          
                 $Job_entity_id=$row_app['Job_entity_id'];
                 //get jobseeker job_entity           
                 $get_job="select * from job_entity where id='$Job_entity_id'";
                 $run_job=mysqli_query($con, $get_job);
                 while($row_job=mysqli_fetch_array($run_job)){
                    $id=$row_job['id'];
                    $Title=$row_job['Title'];    
      ?>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="my_account.php?job=<?php echo $id; ?>"><span><?php echo $Title; ?></span></a>
    <?php } } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it has more entities and jobseeker applied for more than one job

Comment: Yes that makes more sens